# Переход на gulp 4 версии,

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

Смотрю курс по верстке html письма и видимо после обновления gulp стала вылетать ошибка, как мне её исправить, я уже читал документацию, смотрел похожие вопросы на форумах, но решения пока не увидел.
Help.
Версия gulp 4.0.0

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    inky = require('inky'),
    inlineCss = require('gulp-inline-css'),
    inlineSource = require('gulp-inline-source');


//STYLES
gulp.task('styles', function () {
    return gulp.src('./scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

//CONVERTE INKY
gulp.task('inky', ['styles'], function () {
    return gulp.src('./templates/**/*.html')
        .pipe(inlineSource())
        .pipe(inky())
        .pipe(inlineCss({
            preserveMediaQueries: true,
            removeLinkTags: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});

//WATCH
gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.watch(['./scss/**/*.scss', './templates/**/*.html'], ['inky']);
});
```

И текст ошибки:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\newsletter-video-tut>gulp
assert.js:350
    throw err;
    ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\newsletter-video-tut\node_
modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\newsletter-video-tut\node_modules\under
taker\lib\task.js:13:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\newsletter-video-tut\gulpfile.
js:16:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at execute (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\ver
sioned\^4.0.0\index.js:36:18)
    at Liftoff.handleArguments (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
gulp-cli\index.js:175:63)
    at Liftoff.execute (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli
\node_modules\liftoff\index.js:203:12)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\
node_modules\flagged-respawn\index.js:51:3)
    at Liftoff.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp
-cli\node_modules\liftoff\index.js:195:5)
    at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\node_modules\lif
toff\index.js:165:9
```

Comment: Текст ошибки - это тайна? :) Впрочем, и так понятно. В 4 версии `gulp.task()` больше не принимает массив списка зависимостей в качестве параметра. Замените `gulp.task('inky', ['styles'], function () {` на `gulp.task('inky', series(['styles']), function () {`. Надеюсь, кто-нибудь напишет нормальный ответ. :)

Comment: Да, текст ошибки действительно нужно было добавить. Протупил.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно было добавить gulp.series(['название task'])

В итоге файл работает:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    inky = require('inky'),
    inlineCss = require('gulp-inline-css'),
    inlineSource = require('gulp-inline-source');


//STYLES
gulp.task('styles', function () {
    return gulp.src('./scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

//CONVERTE INKY
gulp.task('inky', gulp.series(['styles']), function () {
    return gulp.src('./templates/**/*.html')
        .pipe(inlineSource())
        .pipe(inky())
        .pipe(inlineCss({
            preserveMediaQueries: true,
            removeLinkTags: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});

//WATCH
gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.watch(['./scss/**/*.scss', './templates/**/*.html'], gulp.series(['inky']));
});
```